# Multi row tab (html /css)

Tags: html, css

I am having this problem on my tabs

[image]

If someone cal help for dynamic tab
http://jsfiddle.net/luckyme/sw136sev/11/

The problem is that is not removing the old tab completely run the code to understand well

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabs").tabs();
  $("button#add-tab").click(function() {
    var num_tabs = $(".tabs ul li").length+1;
    if(num_tabs %2 == 0){
         if('.ad'){$('.ad').remove();
                //$('d').remove();
                    $(".tabs").tabs("refresh");
                  }
                      $(".tabs ul").append("<li  ><a href='#tab2'class='ad' >[] " + num_tabs + "</a></li>");
                       $(".tabs").append("<div id='tab2' class='ad'>" + num_tabs + "</div>");
                        $(".tabs").tabs("refresh");
         }      
    else {  
       if('.amm'){$('.amm').remove();
                 // $('.di').remove();
                    $(".tabs").tabs("refresh");
                 } 
                  $(".tabs ul").append("<li ><a href='#tab3' class='amm' >#" + num_tabs + "</a></li>" );
                    $(".tabs").append("<div class='amm' id='tab3' >" + num_tabs + "</div>");
                        $(".tabs").tabs("refresh");         
       }
  });                    
});
```

Comment: This question does not come close to containing enough information to receive help from the community. If you would like assistance with fixing these tabs you will need to supply some of your code so that others can see what you're doing and help to fix it for you. A jsfiddle.net would be nice.

Comment: is hard to show it to u is only inside my project when i do the same code in jsfiddle it doesn't give me any problem.

Comment: Posting the code could still give others insight to why it is not working as intended in your project.

Comment: the code is in a jQuery that add the tabs dynamically . http://jsfiddle.net/luckyme/3ovdLw26/6/  whit this u may have an idea